# Error o Azure Synapse Analytics - Could not allocate a new page for database

Tags: azure, space, disk, azure-synapse

We are receiving some errors on Azure Synaspse Analytics - Azure Data WareHouse.

The following message: `Could not allocate a new page for database 'Distribution_12' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.`

It's starts to happen after the last Syanpse release, on Jun 26Th, 2020.

On begining, it apperars only on huge data movements jobs, today, it is happening in almost of SQL jobs.

Comment: Azure support should be your first point of call.